# Removing line break powershell

Tags: powershell, line-breaks

I am having an issue with a line break in my data. The array was made with an out-string followed by -split. If you want to see that part of the script let me know.

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
"_"+$item+"_"
}
```

Output:

```
_
itemname_
```

Desired Output:

```
itemname
```

I've tried inserting:

```
$item.replace('`','')
```

Without any change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I think this should work. I was under the impression you wanted those underscores in the result.

```
$array -replace "`n|`r"
```

Comment: No success, that just adds `_` before and after $array

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Post some test data, and exactly what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Funnily enough if you go and Google 'Powershell remove newline character' I think the first response is a TechNet post asking a very similar question and mjolinor gave up the answer there too. `$array=$array -replace "``n|``r",""` should do what you want, though his original answer included the tab character too I think. Edit:bah, the double graves should be single graves.

Comment: Sorry, I was putting the `_` in there to show the new line used. So I've tried `$array=$array -replace "``n|``r",""`, `$array=$array -replace '``n|``r',''`, `$array=$array -replace "`n|`r",""` with no success

Comment: Edited again. What version of PS are you using?

Comment: PS v2, It looks like I have both `n and `r in my array. I can't get ` to show up

Comment: `$file = $file.replace("`n","")` works within the foreach loop, but not on the whole array

Comment: That will work for one object, so you'll have to foreach through the array and do them one at a time.  The -replace will do the entire array at once.

Comment: `` $array=$array -replace "`n","" `` works for array. Thanks!!

Comment: There's your answer, then.

Comment: To clarify this topic for PowerShell 7.1+: I just discovered, that PowerShell 5 added `\r\n` to a here-string (i.e. Windows line break), whereas PowerShell 7.1.4 adds `\n`, (i.e. Unix line breaks). This caused my previous code for merging multiple lines to fail: `-replace "'r'n", '|'`. The following is an alternative that works with both versions of PowerShell: `-replace "'r" -replace "'n", '|'`. Note that the single quotes should be backquotes, which can't apparently be escaped here.

Answer (score 2):

By default, 'Get-Content' command has the default delimiter of a new line '\n'.  Create a costume parameter and then do your replace command.  Hope this helps.

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Content -Delimiter "~" | foreach { $_ -replace "`r|`n","" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well how about applying mjolinor's code at the $item level, e.g.:

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
  $item -replace '^|$','_'
}
```

Although I expect the same result you are already getting, there are newlines embedded in your string.

I'm not able to setup the same condition in $array myself, maybe you could post that code.

Does this work?:

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
  $item.Trim() -replace '^|$','_'
}
```

Comment: `$array=$array -replace "``n",""` worked for me (with a single `). Still want me to check other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
"_"+$item.Trim()+"_"
}
```

Should do what you want.