# Need to remove the last carriage return using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a text file by bcp sql server command. I want to remove the last row's carriage return in order to remove the last blank line of text file.

I tried various options but none worked for me. I tried the below option which is only creating a new file with the first line of my text file.

```dos
  set "first="
   <nul (for /f "delims=" %%a in (%source%) do (
      if defined first (echo() else (set "first=1")
      set /p ".=%%a" 
   ))> %dest%
```

It would be great if anyone could help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I guess you mean the last line-break which is actually composed by a carriage-return and a line-feed character, am I right?

Comment: Do you really need to use a batch file? Powershell (considering it has always been there for the last decade and was made default since [the latest Windows 10](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/11/18/windows_cmdexe_deposed_by_powershell/)) or WSH (VBS, JS) would be much more appropriate for this. [Removing line break powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22238465/995714)

Comment: Why do you need to remove carriage return and line-feed from end of file? In my point of view a text file __not__ ending with a line termination ends with a string at end of file, but not with a line at end of file. Many not good coded applications have problems in reading in a text file correct if the last line of a text file has no line termination, i.e. is just a string at end of file. It is nearly always better that a text file with multiple lines has also a line termination at end of file for the last line.

Comment: Supposing you have set the used variables correctly, I cannot see any error in the code; the only things I would change are: 1. `for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("<%source%") do ` to disable the default `eol` character `;` and to allow spaces in the file name; 2. `set /P ="%%a"` to not lose surrounding quotes; 3. `> "%dest%"` to allow spaces in the file name; note that `for /F` does not iterate empty lines, so they become lost; also note that `set /P` removes leading white-spaces and does not allow `=` to be the first character...